# Need some help keeping by accordion menu open on page load.

Tags: jquery, menu, accordion

The code below functions great accept that when I select a link the accordion closes on page load. I would like the accordion to stay open. Please see below. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

http://www.kipjonesart.com/

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    //ACCORDION BUTTON ACTION (ON CLICK DO THE FOLLOWING)
    $('.accordionButton').click(function() {

        //REMOVE THE ON CLASS FROM ALL BUTTONS
        $('.accordionButton').removeClass('on');

        //NO MATTER WHAT WE CLOSE ALL OPEN SLIDES
        $('.accordionContent').slideUp('normal');

        //IF THE NEXT SLIDE WASN'T OPEN THEN OPEN IT
        if($(this).next().is(':hidden') == true) {

            //ADD THE ON CLASS TO THE BUTTON
            $(this).addClass('on');

            //OPEN THE SLIDE
            $(this).next().slideDown('normal');
         } 

     });


    /*** REMOVE IF MOUSEOVER IS NOT REQUIRED ***/

    //ADDS THE .OVER CLASS FROM THE STYLESHEET ON MOUSEOVER 
    $('.accordionButton').mouseover(function() {
        $(this).addClass('over');

    //ON MOUSEOUT REMOVE THE OVER CLASS
    }).mouseout(function() {
        $(this).removeClass('over');                                        
    });

    /*** END REMOVE IF MOUSEOVER IS NOT REQUIRED ***/


    /********************************************************************************************************************
    CLOSES ALL S ON PAGE LOAD
    ********************************************************************************************************************/   
    $('.accordionContent').hide('');

});
</script>
</head>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the pages are new, you need a mechanism that tells the accordion to be open right from when the page is loaded.

Something like:

`<body id="YourPageId">`

on document ready:

`$('.myAccordionSelector').accordion( "option", "active", YourPageId );`